# angularjs does not bind from $http.get factory

Tags: angularjs, web-services, rest

I'm new to angular and I've followed some courses to get things going...

Right now I hooked up my website with a webservice(REST) and bind some results (JSON) to a html table.

The webservice works fine when i'm running the website, through the angular controller triggering the factory and the $http.get it hits the breakpoint in my webservice and returns the JSON.

The thing is, I don't see the expected data on the 'Name' tag in my table. 
I do see that my table 'expands' so it seems some data is put it, but it's just blank.

this is what i've got so far:

JSON Response:

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"E-Plan"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Preliminary Drawing"},{"Id":3,"Name":"Preliminary Design"},{"Id":4,"Name":"Department Layout"}]
```

Table:

```
<div class="projecttypetable" style="overflow-x:auto;">
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr data-ng-repeat="pt in projectTypes">
                <td>
                    <p><b>{{pt.Name}}</b></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>      
    </div>
```

angular controller:

```
spftApp.controller('ProjectTypeController', function ($scope, projectTypesFactory) {

    projectTypesFactory.async().then(function(d) {
        $scope.projectTypes = d;
    });
});
```

Angular Factory:

```
spftApp.factory('projectTypesFactory', function ($http) {

    var urlBase = 'http://localhost:49165/Service1.svc/projectTypes'

    return {
        async: function () {
            return $http.get(urlBase);
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I found the solution by now... It was working fine, I just had to add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to my web config!

Answer (score 1):

The data is in d.data. Try this:

```
spftApp.controller('ProjectTypeController', function ($scope, projectTypesFactory) {

    projectTypesFactory.async().then(function(d) {
       $scope.projectTypes = d.data;
    });
});
```

For more info check [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) documentation.

Answer (score -2):

update your angular factory as below

Angular Factory :

```
spftApp.factory('projectTypesFactory', function ($http) {

var urlBase = 'http://localhost:49165/Service1.svc/projectTypes'

return {
    async: function () {
        return $http.get(urlBase).then(function(response) {
           return response;          

    });
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: OP was trying to return `promise` rather then `response`, I guess :)

Comment: Hi,  i tried both suggestions, but it still results in an empty HTML table. 

One thing i tried is working with a static object instead of an HTML get, and that works fine, so the HTML table is working

Could there be a certain setting that prevents the browser from displaying data? I read somewhere that IIS Express is causing some issues...